# Checking if logged user is administrator

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I'm working on netbeans, building a POS.
I am logged and can all users will be able to do almost everything, except clicking the Config button.
I wanted to make a checker if the user that is logged is adm or not, in my sql database i have an isAdmin variable so if the user is admin it will redirect to another jframe else it will show a pop-up saying acess denied or something.
I know how to do the if and else, just didn't found out how to check the isAdmin yet.
For the loggin verification i used this code:

```
con = sqlConnect.ConnectDB();
    try{
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY username=? and BINARY password=?");
        pst.setString(1, jUsername.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jPassword.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            menuUI menu = new menuUI();
            menu.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }else{
            dadosErrados.setText("*Username ou password incorretos.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

What i was trying for the isAdmin checker was something like:

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE isAdmin=?");
```

But i don't think this is the right way

Comment: Keep the original SQL and read the `isAdmin` column from the `ResultSet` to determine if the user is an admin.  Side bar: note that isAdmin column in the users table is somewhat wasteful since the column will likely be false for most users and true for only a few users.  Consider a separate table such as user_roles, where a role could be "ADMIN".  If the user is not an admin then there is no record.

Comment: but the loggin checker is used in a different UI than the isAdmin checker, is that possible anyways? i've been trying it for a while

Comment: You should also separate the code - see single responsibility principle. 
 Consider a UsersQuery class which only looks up a user, so it is unaware of any GUI code.  The GUI code can invoke the query class when needed.

Comment: i'll try it, thanks a lot :)